# get curves from polylines to create a detail line

Tags: python, ironpython, revit-api, revitpythonshell

I am trying to create a script that can create detail lines from the selection.

Though the lines are as big as around 5' each the script say the following error:

> Exception : Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.ArgumentsInconsistentException: Curve length is too small for Revit's tolerance (as identified by Application.ShortCurveTolerance)
>   Parameter name: endpoints

My code is:

```
#Import Autodesk stuffs
import clr
import System
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')
from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection import *

clr.AddReference('RevitNodes')
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion)
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager

# Import iron python packages
import sys
pyt_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib'
sys.path.append(pyt_path)

import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager


app = __revit__.Application
Ui = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
view = doc.ActiveView

#TransactionManager.Instance.ForceCloseTransaction()
#t = Transaction(doc, "Create CAD Copy")  
#t.Start()

from Autodesk.Revit.UI import Selection


selection = [ doc.GetElement( elId ) for elId in __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Selection.GetElementIds() ]
curve = []
opt = Options()

allGeom =[]
solidGeoms=[]
for i in selection:
    geo = i.get_Geometry(opt)
    for a in geo:
        geo = a.GetInstanceGeometry()
        for g in geo:
            allGeom.append(g)

Lines=filter(lambda x : type(x)==Line,allGeom)

polylines1=filter(lambda x : type(x)==PolyLine,allGeom)
polylines2=filter(lambda x : type(x)==PolyLine,allGeom)

polypoints1=[]

for i in polylines1:
    a = i.GetCoordinates()
    polypoints1.Add(a)


pointlist1=[]
for i in polypoints1:
    j=i
    i.RemoveAt(0)
    pointlist1.append(i)
print(pointlist1)


polypoints2=[]

for i in polylines2:
    a = i.GetCoordinates()
    polypoints2.Add(a)


pointlist2=[]
for i in polypoints2:
    j=i
    m=i.Count
    i.RemoveAt((m-1))
    pointlist2.append(i)
print(pointlist2)

line=[]
for i in pointlist1:
    for j in pointlist2:
        for a in i: 
            for b in j:
                line.append(Line.CreateBound(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You four nested `for` loops will be generating a heck of a lot of lines. I cannot imagine that you really need all of those. You could add an assertion guaranteeing that the minimum distance between `a` and `b` is always larger than, say, a tenth of an inch, ca. 2.5 mm. I bet that assertion will fire. In other words, some of your lines are probably shorter than 5'. Maybe some are even zero length?